# Dynamic routes with code splitting chunks don't seem to work

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-router-v4, code-splitting

I'm using react-router with code-splitting. Dynamic routes like `AuthenticatedRoute` don't seem to work well with it.

If the user goes to the `About` route, logs in and gets back to the `About` route (without refreshing the page), nothing will be shown because the `About` route code-splitting chunk doesn't get replaced/updated and it doesn't have the `About` component imported.

The code:

**Routes**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import asyncComponent from "./AsyncComponent";
import AuthenticatedRoute from "./AuthenticatedRoute";

const AsyncHome = asyncComponent(() => import("../../containers/Home/Home"));
const AsyncAbout = asyncComponent(() => import("../../containers/About/About"));
const AsyncLogin = asyncComponent(() => import("../../containers/Login/Login"));

const Routes = () => (
  <main>
    <Route exact path="/" component={AsyncHome} />
    <AuthenticatedRoute exact path="/about" component={AsyncAbout} />
    <Route exact path="/login" component={AsyncLogin} />
  </main>
)

export default Routes
```

**AuthenticatedRoute**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class AuthenticatedRoute extends Component {
  render() {
    const { props } = this;

    const { component: C, user, ...newProps } = props;

    const renderComponent = (routeProps) => {
      return user ? <C {...routeProps} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />;
    }

    return <Route {...newProps} render={renderComponent} />
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.auth.user
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
}, dispatch)

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(AuthenticatedRoute)
```

The problem seems to be related with the generation of chunks. If the `About` route chunk is created without the user logged in, the chunk will not have the `About` component there. If I refresh the page after logging in, the `About` route chunk has the `About` component there and all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think when the user is not logged in it does not render your component because it goes in else part of this if statement. It will never route to about page unless user is logged in.

```
return user ? <C {...routeProps} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />;
```

Comment: That is working as intended when the user is not logged in. The problem appears if the user logs in but the code-splitting chunk for the About route is the same, which leads to the About component not showing up.